# Can't Use Autosizing Textview with Support Library

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, support-v4

I have the following text view, which is supposed to contain auto sizing text.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabRecyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/lightshade"
    android:text="@string/add_favorites_message"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="2"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

However,  I am getting the error "unexpected namespace prefix "app"" in reference to the last line.

I find this odd because I am using the following support libraries in my `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

I'm using [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) as my guide.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tabRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/imageRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/lightshade"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_favorites_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/lightshade"
        android:text="@string/add_favorites_message"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:maxLines="2" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any other Layout enclosing your TextView and inside your ConstraintLayout where you have delcared xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ?

Comment: I'll post the full layout, but I believe not. I don't think the problem is with the app prefix itself, because the other "app" prefixes work fine. The only one that is problematic is the one on the bottom line of the `TextView` that enables auto resizing text.

Comment: Whats your targetSdkVersion in your build.gradle?

Comment: target and compile sdk version are both 27

Comment: It's really awkward. I know it may be a silly suggestion but, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: Yes, I have. Unfortunately, the error still remains.

Comment: Can you add a more detailed stack of the error?

Comment: There is no stack. It's just an error displayed by the IDE.

Comment: A more detailed log of the error then... If you want, just trying to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172453/discussion-between-roymunson-and-facundo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the `TextView` to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/add_favorites_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabRecyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:background="@color/lightshade"
    android:text="@string/add_favorites_message"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="2"
    />
```

This answer doesn't make sense to me because the first answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017163/support-libraries-to-add-for-autosizing-textviews?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post, says I shouldn't have to do this. But at least the error is gone.